# The relation between positive definite matrix and its ellipsoid

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-analysis, ellipsoids

Define $S^n_{++}$ to be the set that contains all the positive definite matrices. That is, if $A \in S^n_{++}$, then $A$ is a positive definite matrix.

Then, we associate with each $A \in S^n_{++}$ an ellipsoid centered at the origin, given by

$$\varepsilon_A = \{x \mid x^T A^{-1} x \leq 1\}.$$

How to prove that for two positive definite matrices $A,B \in S^n_{++}$,
$$B - A \in S^n_{++}$$
if and only if
$$\varepsilon_A \subseteq \varepsilon_B?$$

---

This is related to Example 2.18 on Professor Boyd's textbook "[Convex Optimization](http://stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf)". I'm learning it by myself now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115820/b-a-in-sn-and-i-a1-2b-1a1-2-in-sn-equivalent#1115820) as follows:
$$
B - A \in S^n_{++} \iff\\
I - B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2} \in S^n_{++} \iff\\
I - A^{1/2}B^{-1}A^{1/2} \in S^n_{++} \iff\\
A^{-1} - B^{-1} \in S^n_{++}
$$