# Positive definiteness and eigenvalue ellipses

Tags: matrices, inequality, positive-definite

if non-symmetric square matrices **A** and **B** holds the following inequality:

**A** $\ge$ **B**

Can I say that matrix **A**'s eigenvalue ellipse encloses that of **B**'s in case of 2D?

By eigenvalue ellipse, I mean an ellipse formed by semi major axis with the magnitude of bigger eigenvalue directed in the associated eigenvector, and semi minor axis vice-versa with the smaller eigenvalue.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The relation between positive definite matrix and its ellipsoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1114132/the-relation-between-positive-definite-matrix-and-its-ellipsoid)

Comment: Yes, this is true if $A$ and $B$ are have positive eigenvalues (which you for the ellipses to be nondegenerate, i.e. not a line or a point), see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1114132/the-relation-between-positive-definite-matrix-and-its-ellipsoid). This is because $A - B \ge 0$ (which means that $A - B$ is symmetric) is equivalent to $B^{-1} - A^{-1} \ge 0$, which gives the inclusion of ellipses.